Does PieCloudDB support Flink?
I want to synchronize the data in MySQL to PieCloudDB for data analysis. Does PieCloudDB offer native support for using Apache Flink as a data synchronization tool? Are there any specific configurations or plugins that need to be set up within PieCloudDB to enable Flink?

Yes, PieCloudDB has PieCloudDB Flink Connector, which can efficiently import data from Flink into PieCloudDB and supports Flink SQL and Flink DataStream API. Note that you need to make sure that the flink checkpoint function is turned on before using it.
